# "step by step" solution to upload a png image from my desktop named "snap"

Tags: support, images, help-center

I want to upload an image from my desktop, but I can't. I read
https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images
but can't operate. I need a "step by step" solution to upload a png image from my desktop named "snap". Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When composing your post, click the image button, bordered in red below.

$\hspace{3.5cm}$[image: image button]

That should bring up the "Add Image" dialog:

$\hspace{2.5cm}$[image: Add Image dialog]

In the "Add Image" dialog, click the "Browse..." button and select the image file to upload. Then click the "Add picture" button. Your image should appear in your post.

Comment: What?! No mention of the very convenient "drag-and-drop" option?